# Trying to use a loop to print each item in the list and then delete item Python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

```
names = ['Gary', 'Becky', 'Tyler', 'Andy', 'Bob', 'Eric', 'Elliott']
for n in names:
    del names[0]
print(names)
```

I am trying to declare a list of names called names. I want the for loop to cycle through each item in the list from point [0], and for each item, I want it to delete the item in the first spot in the list names. It is returning like the last 4 items in the list. Where am I getting confused? I then want it to print the empty names list

Comment: Don't modify a list as you iterate over it.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. I was just trying to understand how it was working. Is it bad to modify a list during iteration?

Answer (score 0):

You could try it out this way,

```
for n in range(0, len(names)):
     names.pop(0)
```

Hope it helped